# What does a transition from static IP to BGP look like?

Tags: bgp

We initially got a /30 from our upstream and now we're ready to start running BGP to advertise our own /24.

What does that sort of process typically look like? Does it likely require some prior coordination or do we just call the NOC and tell them we want to establish a BGP session?

What IP address do you normally use for that? The /30 they gave us or one of our /24 addresses or just a private address?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Typically you need to coordinate BGP configurations with your ISP, as they need to configure your upstream router. 
You should be able to use your /30 for peering.

Answer (score 1):

If you are only connected to one ISP, you could probably have them statically route your /24 to your end of the /30, and then originate the /24 from their AS#. You would still need a static default route to their end of the /30.

If you choose to go BGP you will also need your own AS#